# WAMP 2.4 PHP 5.4 - Fatal error for db2_connect()

Tags: php, wamp, db2-connect

Can't seem to find a fix for this.

Have: 
- WAMP 2.4
- PHP 5.4.12
- php_ibm_db2.dll extension on in the php.ini file and the file in the ext folder.
I get

> **Fatal error: Call to undefined function db2_connect() in** I see
>   this in the apache_erro.log
>  "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/php_ibm_db2.dll' -
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0"

Any idea's how to get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer did you install, the 32bit or the 64bit?

Comment: Have you installed the `IBM DB2 Universal Database client` on the PC running WAMPServer?

Comment: Looks like I'm using the 32 bit version....Doesn't look like I have IBM DB2 Universal Database client installed...I just have IBM DB2 9.7 stuff installed for windows.